# Why does javascript's "in" operator return true when testing if 0 exists in an array that doesn't contain 0?

Tags: javascript, arrays, in-operator

Why does the "in" operator in Javascript return true when testing if "0" exists in array, even when the array doesn't appear to contain "0"?

For example, this returns true, and makes sense:

```
var x = [1,2];
1 in x; // true
```

This returns false, and makes sense:

```
var x = [1,2];
3 in x; // false
```

However this returns true, and I don't understand why:

```
var x = [1,2];
0 in x;
```

Comment: this logic is valid in python not in javascript

Answer (score 86, accepted):

It refers to the index or key, not the value.  `0` and `1` are the valid indices for that array.  There are also valid keys, including `"length"` and `"toString"`.  Try `2 in x`.  That will be false (since JavaScript arrays are 0-indexed).

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).

Answer (score 22):

The `in` operator doesn't do what you're thinking it does. The `in` operator returns `true` if the specified operand is a property of the object. For arrays, it returns `true` if the operand is a valid *index* (which makes sense if think of arrays as a special-case object where the properties are simply named 0, 1, 2, ...)

For example, try this:

```
var x=[1,4,6];
alert(2 in x);
```

It'll also return `true`, because "2" is a valid index into the array. In the same way, "0" is an index into the array, so also returns `true`.

Comment: *"(which makes sense if think of arrays as a special-case object where the properties are simply named 0, 1, 2, ..."* Which is what they are, per the spec. JavaScript engines optimize them when possible of course. :-)

Answer (score 15):

I guess you use Python before, in JS, use Array.prototype.includes

```
let x = [1, 2]
x.includes(1) // true
```

*in* operator check the indices of the array not the value

```
0 in [1, 2] // true
2 in [1, 2] // false
```

Comment: I thought JS's `in` keyword works similar with Python's LOL

Answer (score 9):

Javascript's `in` operator does not check if a value is contained in an array.  It checks if the object has a property or index.  So `var x = [4,5]; 4 in x; //false 1 in x; //true`.

Because length is a property of x, `"length" in x; //true`

Answer (score 8):

Modern browsers, except IE, support a couple methods that can find a value
 in an array.

indexOf and lastIndexOf return the first(or last) index of an exact match
of their argument in an array, or -1, if no matching element was found.

```
if(A.indexOf(0)!= -1){
    // the array contains an element with the value 0.
}
```

You can add one or both methods to IE and older browsers-

```
if(![].indexOf){
    Array.prototype.indexOf= function(what, i){
        i= i || 0;
        var L= this.length;
        while(i< L){
            if(this[i]=== what) return i;
            ++i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    Array.prototype.lastIndexOf= function(what, i){
        var L= this.length;
        i= i || L-1;
        if(isNaN(i) || i>= L) i= L-1;
        else if(i< 0) i += L;
        while(i> -1){
            if(this[i]=== what) return i;
            --i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you providing a workaround to the problem rather than just an explanation as to why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

just like the js `for in` loop which iterates the object properties, the `in` operator checks if the specified property is in the specified object or its **prototype** chain. it does not check whether an *element* is in an array.

let's say x is an *array*, use `x.includes(element)` to return `true/false` in nodejs/modern-browsers.  As for `loop`, use `for(let element of x)` since x is a js `iterable`.