# Why does the `in` operator not return true for a value that is present in the array?

Tags: javascript

I've got small problem in understanding the `in` operator in JavaScript.  Why doesn’t it return true in example below?

```js
const ar = [4];

console.log(ar);
console.log(ar[0]);
console.log(4 in ar);
```

Comment: The `in` operator tests the **keys** not **values**.

Comment: @dave An array is an object, it just has numeric keys.

Comment: @dave in javascript arrays **are** objects, it's not working because there's no fifth item (fourth index) in the array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does javascript's "in" operator return true when testing if 0 exists in an array that doesn't contain 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067072/why-does-javascripts-in-operator-return-true-when-testing-if-0-exists-in-an-a)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `in` operator tests whether the given property name exists in an object, it doesn't search the values. `a in ar` will be true if `ar[a]` exists. In your example, `ar[0]` exists, but `ar[4]` doesn't, so `a in ar` is false.

To search values in an array, use the `includes` function. It returns `true` if the array has that element, or `false` if the value can't be found.

```
if (!ar.includes(a)) {
    console.log("in if");
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
I programmed a lot in python so i assumed that its the same as python.

Comment: Nope. It's also not the same when you write `for (x in obj)`, that sets `x` to the property names of the object, not the values.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `in` operator is looking for property names, not property values.

It works fine for arrays, but you need to specify the index of the item, not the value:

```js
var ar = [];
var index = 4;
var value = 5;
ar[index] = value;

if (index in ar){
    console.log("in if");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using in with Array you should use index/key and not the value.
Below will have the if condition true.

Ex:

```
var ar = [];
var a = 4;
ar.push(a);
if(0 in ar){
  console.log("in if");
}
```

You can use property name when working with object.
Ex:

```
var student = {name: "John", lastName: "Cena", age: 30};
if(name in student){
  console.log("in if");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine an object and an array that looks like this:

```
var obj = { foo: "bar" };
var arr = ["bar"];
```

You would access the `obj`'s `bar` value by invoking the corresponding key on that object, i.e.

```
obj.foo // "bar"
```

An alternative way of doing this would be to use the array syntax:

```
obj["foo"] // "bar"
```

As you can see, each of the object's keys has a name (i.e. foo). An array is still an object, only that it's 'keys' (or indexes) are incremental numeric values. Thusly, we access the various elements in the array using their respective indexes in that array, i.e:

```
arr[0] // "bar"
```

In this way, use of the `in` keyword should become clearer. MDN defines the `in` keyword as the following:

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object.

So, in keeping with our previous example, consider the following:

```
"foo" in obj // true
"bar" in obj // false
```

The above happens because, as you already know, the variable `obj` only has one element in it, and that element's **key** is `foo`, and it's **value** is bar. With this in mind, consider your array:

```
var ar = [];
var a = 4;
ar.push(a);

0 in ar // true
4 in ar // false
```

As you can now hopefully see, in much the same way it investigates the js object, for arrays the `in` keyword is still looking for the *key* and not for the value corresponding to that key. Though the **value** at index 0 is 4, it's **key** (or index) is still 0. Hence, it should be clear why calling

```
4 in ar // false
```

Returns `false` - there's nothing in that array's fourth index. Hope this helps.