# Javascript string IN array of string doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've noticed that the following results hold:

```js
1 in [1,2,3] == true
['a','b','c'].includes('a') == true
```

But

```js
'a' in ['a'] == false
```

This happens in both node and the browser.

Why? Can someone link me an article to read more about it?

Comment: `in` checks if *the key* exists, not the value.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: aaaahh. Because I chose 1,2,3 it worked, becuase the array was 1 long. HAHAHAHA

Comment: Thanks guys, updoot for you both

Comment: It just happen to work for int, it was never supposed to work or be used for arrays. 1 in ['a','b','c'] certainly returns true also

Comment: I'm certain there is a near exact dupe of this but the damn search doesn't want to cooperate. `in` is very hard to find, since it's too short...

Comment: Hey, same. I did a phat search beforehand. :3

Comment: @Rajesh hahaha, I just found it and came back to link it and you've closed it seconds before me :D I *knew* I've seen that question, so I had to dig.

Comment: aight, fair enough, but mine has a string heheh. I hope this stays on the record anyways :D

Comment: @VLAZ I went to search for some reference material that would help make my answer better but found this...  Funny world

Comment: @Thornkey yeah, I thought the other one had a string, too. Seems I was wrong. Still - no worries, having duplicates is a good thing, since it makes the canonical Q&A easier to find. Something that really frustrated me, since I found [another question for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505144/in-operator-issue-in-javascrip) while searching but it wasn't linked, so it was even harder to find the one with more answers and better explanation.

Answer (score -1):

The experiment worked but only coincidentally. The key `1` existed in the array because the array happened to be 3 items long. So, the below wouldn't work:

```js
4 in [4,5] == false
```

And the below would work:

```js
1 in ["a","b"] == true
```