# Difference between in and includes in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I was very surprised to find out that:

```
> 'a' in ['a', 'b']
false
> ['a','b'].includes('a')
true
```

What does each command perform in NodeJS?

Comment: [Why does javascript's "in" operator return true when testing if 0 exists in an array that doesn't contain 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3067072) | [In operator issue in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33505144) |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not node specific but ECMA (JS) specific.

##### [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) Operator

Checks the existence of key in the collection (similar to [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)but also check inherited keys in prototype chain)

##### [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method of Array (introduced in ES6)

Checks the existence of value in the collection

Answer (score 1):

`Array.includes()` checks for the existence of a certain value in an array, while the `in` operator checks for the existence of a key in an object (or an index in the case of arrays like you're describing).

```js
console.log('a' in ['a', 'b']); // false, no such key
console.log(0 in ['a', 'b']); // true, 0 is a key that exists
console.log(1 in ['a', 'b']); // true, 1 is a key that exists
console.log(2 in ['a', 'b']); // false, 2 is a key that doesn't exists
```