# Remove duplicate in array

Tags: javascript, duplicates

This doesn't work:

```
result = [1, 4, 5, 5, 5];

var newData = result.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
if (cur in acc === false) {
  acc.push(cur);
}
return acc;
},[]);

console.log(newData);
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

I know one workable way, like replace the `if()` condition with the following code:

```
if (acc.length == 0 || acc[acc.length-1] !== cur) {
  acc.push(cur);
}
```

which gives expected output:

```
[1, 4, 5]
```

My question is why the first way doesn't work?

Comment: [Because `in` doesn't work](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/OT@vOD8nVS8nP13DQCEzTyHaMFbT@v9/AA).

Comment: (i.e., it checks for key existence)

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/best-way-to-find-if-an-item-is-in-a-javascript-array).

Comment: `in` doesn't work. You can try change this: `cur in acc === false` to this: `acc.indexOf(cur) == -1`

Comment: [Better dupe target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067072/why-does-javascripts-in-operator-return-true-when-testing-if-0-exists-in-an-a).

Answer (score -1):

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object or its prototype chain.

For each value in `result`, it is returning `false`. Hence, you are getting all the values of the result in your accumulator. In case of an array, `in` checks for the index.

```js
var result = [1, 4, 5, 5, 5];

var newData = result.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  if (cur in acc === false) {
    acc.push(cur);
  }
  return acc;
},[]);

console.log(newData);
```

Instead of using `in`, you can use `includes` or `indexOf`.

```js
var result = [1, 4, 5, 5, 5];

var newData = result.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  if(!acc.includes(cur)) {
    acc.push(cur);
  }
  return acc;
},[]);

console.log(newData);
```

You can use `Set` to get unique values.

```js
var result = [1, 4, 5, 5, 5];
var unique = [...new Set(result)];
console.log(unique);
```