# Return false when use 'in' statement for dom node in javascript

Tags: javascript

I use

```
1 in [1]; // ===> true
```

But

```
const node = document.body.querySelector("div"); 
node in [node]; //===> false
```

Can anyone help me understand？

Comment: `1 in [1];` doesn't return true.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am confused into ‘python’.

Comment: [Why does javascript's “in” operator return true when testing if 0 exists in an array that doesn't contain 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3067072)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> 1 in [1]; // ===> true
> ```

No, that evaluates as `false`. Here is a demo:

```js
console.log(1 in [1]);
```

The `in` operator will evaluate as true if the left-hand side **converted to a string** exists as a property **name** on the right hand side. Your array has a property `'0'` with a value of `1` (and also some other properties like `length` and `indexOf` which are inherited from the `Array` prototype).

The `in` operator doesn't check if the **value** on the left exists as a **value** in the array on the right. You need [the `includes` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for that.

```js
console.log([1].includes(1));
const node = document.body.querySelector("div"); 
console.log([node].includes(node));
```

```html
<div>...</div>
```

Comment: Sorry. I was mistaken, I wanted to delete it, but it was too late, but thank you

Comment: I am confused into ‘python’.